# How to iterate over a custom type and find specific one?

Tags: java

I have an ArrayList of class Olive:

```
ArrayList<Olive> olives = new ArrayList<Olive>();

olives.add(new Kalamata());
olives.add(new Ligurian());
olives.add(new Kalamata());
olives.add(new Ligurian());
```

Inside the kalamata and ligurian classes, I have set their names:

```
this.name = "Ligurian";
this.name = "Kalamata";
```

How can I iterate over the Olive type arrayList?  I want to find where the name variable = "Ligurian" and then return Ligurian.getOrigin()

Comment: Have you tried using a loop? Then `break` after you find and deal with the first item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the streams API:

```
Olive olive = olives.stream()
                     .filter(o -> o.name.equals("Ligurian"))
                     .findAny().get();
String origin = olive.getOrigin();
```

If you're using Java 7 you can use a loop, which is a shame for you but also ok:

```
Olive found;
for(Olive olive : olives) {
    if(olive.name.equals("Ligurian")) {
        found = olive;
        break;
    }
}
String origin = found.getOrigin();
```

Comment: Mind that this is Java 8. Should probably mention that.

Comment: @LigamentThrasher I added a Java 7 answer. Good idea.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, I only implement getOrigin from the ligurian class itself so this way is showing me how to getOrigin from the superclass?

Comment: @Beginnerquestions this is a way to call  `getOrigin` on the first object in the iteration that has a `name` property equal to `"Ligurian"`.  Nothing more nothing less - you can call any `Olive` method on it.

Comment: sorry I am confused how do I get it to be the origin from ligurian class? because found.getOrigin() wants me to implement the method on my superclass.

Comment: Oh, that's bad OOP then, you can cast it to a subtype and it'd work - but it's better to write polymorphic code - either it makes sense to treat it as an olive or it doesn't.

Comment: May I ask why it is bad? because an Olive doesn't have a specific origin but a specific olive will ?  what needs to be done to make it good?

Comment: @Beginnerquestions not create an `ArrayList` of `Olive` in the first place, or create a polymorphic method - check out the official Java tutorial on polymorphism.

Comment: In the stream version, it is better to use `findAny()` rather than `findFirst()` since he isn't specifically looking for the first occurrence.

Comment: @Misha in this specific case it doesn't matter - but in general I agree, I thought `findFirst` would be less confusing to OP - do you feel strongly that findAny would be better here?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum `findAny()` more clearly conveys to the maintainer your intent and it has a performance advantage if the stream were ever made parallel.  It's not a big deal but I think it's a good habit.

Comment: Would I need to set it so that getOrigin() in the superclass then chooses between either a Ligurian or Kalamata class depending on the name?

Comment: Yes, although it depends on bigger perspective - anyway, this is irrelevant to the answer, if you have a new question and it has not been answered yet in another thread ask it as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, iterate over a custom Type and pick out one.

```
for (Olive olive : olives) {
  if (olive instanceof Ligurian) {
    String origin = olive.getOrigin();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider having this class to manage your olives (or anything else):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class TypedList<T> {
  Map<Class<? extends T>,List<T>> mlt;

  public TypedList() {
    mlt = new HashMap<>();
  }

  private <U extends T> void add(Class<U> t,U o) {
    List<U> lu = (List<U>)mlt.get(t);
    if (lu == null) {
      lu = new ArrayList<>();
      mlt.put(t, (List<T>)lu);
    }
    lu.add(o);
  }

  public void add(T o) {
    add((Class<T>)o.getClass(),o);
  }

  public <U extends T> List<U> get(Class<U> t) {
    return (List<U>)mlt.get(t);
  }

  public <U extends T> List<? extends U> getIncludingDescendands(Class<U> t) {
    List<U> nl = new ArrayList<>();
    // Inefficient Unions
    mlt.entrySet().stream().filter((e)->t.isAssignableFrom(e.getKey())).forEach((e)->{nl.addAll((List<U>)e.getValue());});
    return nl;
  }
}
```

Then your main code could look like something like this:

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    TypedList<Olive> olives = new TypedList<>();

    olives.add(new Kalamata());
    olives.add(new Ligurian());
    olives.add(new Kalamata());
    olives.add(new Ligurian());
    olives.add(new BigKalamata());

    System.out.println("Number of Ligurian: "+olives.get(Ligurian.class).size());
    System.out.println("Number of Kalamata: "+olives.get(Kalamata.class).size());
    System.out.println("Number of BigKalamata: "+olives.get(BigKalamata.class).size());
    System.out.println("Number of Kalamata and Subspecies: "+olives.getIncludingDescendands(Kalamata.class).size());
    // get first Ligurian:
    Ligurian ligurian = olives.get(Ligurian.class).get(0); // Carefull for NPE
  }
}
```

Consider also following

```
public interface Olive {}
public class Ligurian implements Olive {}
public class Kalamata implements Olive {}
public class BigKalamata extends Kalamata {}
```

Note that as an additional feature, this would work even without a `getName` being exposed. Rather than using `getName` it uses the class of the added object to subcategorize or partition. Use of the actual class name, like when using `olives.get(Ligurian.class)`, gives as additional benefits that typo's would be caught during compilation time, and the returned object is strongly typed.

Always better to organize your data while you are accumulating it, if the overhead is negligible for doing so. This will make later processing much more efficient (if you code it right). Foresight in how you are going to use it later on helps.

One additional thought might be needed, is what to be done in case of multiple ClassLoader's. I am not sure. Might need to store internally using class name instead.